# Screws for mounting exercise rings on concrete ceiling

Tags: concrete, ceiling, screws

I want to have a pair of still rings for training purposes in my room. To be more specific I want a pair of adjustable and storable still rings and for that, I need two screws in my concrete ceiling. My main concern is that they can hold my body weight. I'm around 65 kg and I will NOT swing with the rings (the room's too shallow anyways). I want to do exercises like L-sits, planche, pull-up, muscle-up etc. So I'd say the screws would need to hold a maximum of 150 kg in an extreme situation.

What size and kind of screw should I take and is there anything else I should be concerned about?

Comment: What thickness should i use with a sleeve anchor?

Comment: You want to drill into the concrete ceiling, and I'm guessing you're renting. If I were your landlord, I wouldn't be enthusiastic about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary types of anchors for concrete. I'd trust either if properly installed. Holes must be drilled cleanly and to the proper size. Bolts must be of the correct diameter and length. Both require fairly large holes (7/16" to 5/8" or so).

Sleeve or Wedge Anchor (with integrated bolt)
[image]

Lag Shield (with standard lag screw)
[image]

Comment: I like the red head type wedge better than the lag , have even done hot sulfur a long time ago that worked better than the lags of that time,,, + for a good answer just realized this was overhead never done that with sulfer just horizontal and ground facing, can't give another + Oops went to 0 then hit it again and 1 + maybe I should remover the site rules,,,